# Boot Linux (arago) from usb instead of sd card on Am-1808

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

I have [Am-1808](http://www.logicpd.com/products/system-on-modules/zoom-am1808/) board (evm zoom kit), Right now I have ubl and uboot in the spi flash, and file system and kernel(uImage) in the SD card, I followed the steps for running linux on am-1808 board from [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/GSG%3a_OMAP-L138_DVEVM_Additional_Procedures#Creating_bootable_SD_card_for_OMAP-L138_EVM_board):

I don't find any official reference/document which can explain booting linux from usb, is it possible that i can place file system + kernel in the usb and then tell the uboot to look for usb to find uImage from usb instead of sd-card. If yes, then can u please explain how?

The portion of u-boot code which looks for uImage from sd card is:

```
#define CONFIG_BOOTARGS     "mem=32M console=ttyS2,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2     rw rootwait ip=off"
#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND  "if mmc rescan 0; then if fatload mmc 0 0xc0600000 boot.scr; then source 0xc0600000; else fatload mmc 0 0xc0700000 uImage; bootm c0700000; fi; else sf probe 0; sf read 0xc0700000 0x80000 0x220000; bootm 0xc0700000; fi"
```

I need to use usb instead of sd-card for placing filesystem + uImage because i had to use sd card pins (mmc0) for some other purposes.

**Update:**

[This](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Booting_Linux_kernel_using_U-Boot#USB_Storage) explains booting linux from usb, but the problem is that u-boot don't recognize the 'usb' command, when i type: usb reset, it gives me this error:

```
U-Boot > usb reset
Unknown command 'usb' - try 'help'
```

The 'usb' command also don't appear in the list of the available commands displayed by the 'help' command.

```
U-Boot > help
?       - alias for 'help'
askenv  - get environment variables from stdin
base    - print or set address offset
bdinfo  - print Board Info structure
boot    - boot default, i.e., run 'bootcmd'
bootd   - boot default, i.e., run 'bootcmd'
bootm   - boot application image from memory
bootp   - boot image via network using BOOTP/TFTP protocol
cmp     - memory compare
coninfo - print console devices and information
cp      - memory copy
crc32   - checksum calculation
dhcp    - boot image via network using DHCP/TFTP protocol
echo    - echo args to console
editenv - edit environment variable
env     - environment handling commands
exit    - exit script
ext2load- load binary file from a Ext2 filesystem
ext2ls  - list files in a directory (default /)
false   - do nothing, unsuccessfully
fatinfo - print information about filesystem
fatload - load binary file from a dos filesystem
fatls   - list files in a directory (default /)
go      - start application at address 'addr'
help    - print command description/usage
iminfo  - print header information for application image
imxtract- extract a part of a multi-image
itest   - return true/false on integer compare
loadb   - load binary file over serial line (kermit mode)
loads   - load S-Record file over serial line
loady   - load binary file over serial line (ymodem mode)
loop    - infinite loop on address range
md      - memory display
mdc     - memory display cyclic
mii     - MII utility commands
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing address)
mmc     - MMC sub system
mmcinfo - display MMC info
mtest   - simple RAM read/write test
mw      - memory write (fill)
mwc     - memory write cyclic
nfs     - boot image via network using NFS protocol
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
ping    - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network host
printenv- print environment variables
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
run     - run commands in an environment variable
saveenv - save environment variables to persistent storage
saves   - save S-Record file over serial line
setenv  - set environment variables
sf      - SPI flash sub-system
showvar - print local hushshell variables
sleep   - delay execution for some time    
source  - run script from memory
sspi    - SPI utility command
test    - minimal test like /bin/sh
tftpboot- boot image via network using TFTP protocol
true    - do nothing, successfully
version - print monitor version
```

Any idea how can i specify the 'usb' command in the u-boot ? Do i need to upgrade uboot to a newer version ?

regards

usama

Comment: This would primarily depend on having a version of u-boot which has USB host drivers for your particular platform, and was built with them enabled.

Comment: yea, i solved that issue by downloading the new uboot source (upgraded version) for my board, which already had usb enabled.